# When overriding a method

Tags: c#

When overriding a method in c#, is it best to implement your own logic before or after the `base.OverridenMethodName()` ?

Comment: Depends on what you're using it for

Comment: You don't need to to call the base implementation at all. It all depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check these things in reflector. The framework does it's job in the InternalOnNavigatedTo method, which calls the empty OnNavigatedTo virtual method:

```
protected virtual void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) { }
```

You can delete that line, it has no function, but this is not a general rule. If you don't know what are the base functions do, leave the calls there.

And hence, depending upon what the base class functionality is, you need to decide where to put you code. either before or after the call to the base method.

So its your call. Check for any trivial functionality in the base and depending upon that decide the place.

Comment: So if I want to extend the functionality, say make it do something extra than it already does, then I should implement my code after the base?

Comment: According to my understanding, If the base is trying to modify something that you will be using in your implementation of the function, then it is wise to place code after the call.
If your addition to the code is independent of what the base was trying to do, you can place it anywhere.

Comment: Do accept the answer if it took you in the right direction. Thanks and cheers :)

Comment: It did, just had to wait 10 minutes to mark it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best".

Does the `base.OverrideMethodName` designed to be called before more specialized code?
Does it designed to be called after?
Does it even designed to be called from more specialized version?

And if you are the owner of the base class, then it's all up to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, from a purely logical point of view, it could be "clearer" to call it before to do anything else, at the beginning of the method.

But it entirely depends of your needs and what does the base and overriden methods : according to that, you could call it at the beginning, at the middle, at the end, or not at all !